# Incorrect rowIndex in saved predictions when input contains missing values

Tags: r, r-caret

I have discovered some unexpected behavior in caret's handling of missing values with respect to the saved predictions that are returned.

Specifically, if `savePredictions = TRUE` is specified, then all predictions made during validation will be saved and returned along with a field `rowIndex`, which specifies to which index of the original input the row corresponds.

However, when there are missing values in the input, and when `na.action` is not specified, these row indices do not match the row indices of the original input. Presumably they line up instead with the rows of the filtered data.

Additionally, the documentation states that the default `na.action` is `na.fail`, but I have not found this to be the case.

I have provided a minimal working example below:

```
library(caret)

data = data.frame(
    ID         = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6),
    predictor  = c(1, 2,NA, 4, 5, 6)
)

ctl <- trainControl(method='cv', number=5, savePredictions=T)

fit <- train(data$ID ~ ., 
             data=data, 
             method='rpart', 
             trControl=ctl, 
             tuneLength = 1,
             tuneGrid = data.frame(.cp = 0))

comparison <- fit$pred
comparison$ID <- data[fit$pred$rowIndex,]$ID    
print(comparison)
```

In the output we expect that `obs` will always equal `rowIndex`, but this not the case. Instead, we get the following output:

```
  pred obs rowIndex cp Resample ID
1 4.25   1        1  0    Fold1  1
2 4.00   2        2  0    Fold2  2
3 3.50   4        3  0    Fold3  3
4 3.25   5        4  0    Fold4  4
5 3.00   6        5  0    Fold5  5
```

Notice that beginning at row 3 (where the NA occurred in the input), the indices are shifted.

When `na.action = na.omit` is specified, I see the same result, but the output is as expected with `na.action = na.roughfix`.

Comment: I suggest using `data.complete <- data[complete.cases(data),]` to avoid this.

Comment: Yes, this works fine if I want to throw out all instances with missing data. If I instead want to impute the data in a nested way, there doesn't really seem to be a way to do that. If I provide `medianImpute` or some other impute method as the preProc argument to the trainControl, this problem still occurs.

Comment: You might want to try on Cross Validated, maybe. It's more focused on stats so you could have better luck finder an answer to that!

Comment: You should add an issue on the [github page](https://github.com/topepo/caret/issues) with a reproducible example and the results of `sessionInfo()`.